# AJAX not redirecting if user unloads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a user if they have logged in to my site and left the page.  I'm not having a problem logging them out or closing the session, however, if they hit the back button on their browser they're able to see the template for the profile page but none of the information associated with the user that was logged in.  I don't want this, I want the user to be redirected to the login page if they hit the browser back button after having navigated away from their profile while logged in.  Is there a way to do this?  If so, how?

This script calls the logout.php page and loggs them out if the page has been unloaded and then checks to see if the page has been reloaded and should redirect them to the logged_out page.  This is what's not working.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function(response){
        if(response.success == "1"){
            if(location.reload(true)){
                location.replace("../pages/logged_out.php");
            }
        }
    }, "json");
})
```

Comment: So the issue is the return to the template? You would need a script at the top of the template page to verify the user is logged in, and a redirect there.

Comment: `if(location.reload(true)){` is always falsy.

Comment: This may be the wrong way to go about getting the user to log out (forfeit their cookie). You may want to try a) chiding the user next time they log in if they closed the page instead of logging out, ala gmx.com, or b) set a different cookie expiration policy.

Comment: @Mark, can you post your response as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @Robert As requested, now an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is redirecting the user after they hit the back button, you should add a check at the top of the Profile/Template page to redirect the user to the login page.

In general practice, this is the very first thing I do at the top of every page (in a function call) so I can make sure no one is hitting a page they shouldn't be if they aren't logged in.